# Diesel cli '`database.sqlite3` is not a valid database URL. It should start with `postgres://`'

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

When running `diesel migration run` on a project with an sqlite database in the ENV, I get this error about not being a valid postgres url.

```
$ diesel migration run
thread 'main' panicked at '`database.sqlite3` is not a valid database URL. It should start with `postgres://`',
```

Cargo.toml from the project

```
[package]
name = "matrix_bot"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["sqlite"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
tokio = {version = "1.14.0", features = ["full"]}
matrix-sdk = "0.4.1"
```

the .env content

```
DATABASE_URL=database.sqlite3
```

Comment: You don't include any code or `Cargo.toml` to show what your configuration was, so the actual problem cannot be seen.

Answer (score 0):

If diesel_cli was installed with *only* the postgres feature enabled, it will no longer work for sqlite databases. The solution is to reinstall the cli via cargo

```
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You do not have to install the CLI with default features disabled to be able to use SQLite. You likely had some other problem in your code or `Cargo.toml`, which you didn't include, so your question is unhelpful.

Comment: @Herohtar Updated to include the cargo.toml. What I observed was this was working perfectly fine, then I went to go through the demo in a separate project/directory which used postgres. When I returned to my existing project I was unable to run the cli until reinstalling it as described.

Comment: The only thing changed from it giving the above error and it running correctly was the cargo install.

Comment: I just ran `cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres` and migrations can no longer be run without any changes to the code (same error as in question). It seems pretty clear that a reinstall _is_ required.

Comment: So that's the key missing detail -- not a code error, but that you had previously installed the CLI with *only* the `postgres` feature. Diesel will obviously not work with a specific database unless the feature for working with that database type is enabled.

Comment: You should just run `cargo install diesel_cli` to include all features, then you will not have any problems. However, this requires dependencies for all three databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL, and SQLite), so if you don't need MySQL and don't want to install that dependency you could run `cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features "postgres sqlite"`. That will allow both of your projects to compile.